# why the useLocation was undefined when access component from shared url

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have defined a component that handle the share link from url like this:

```
import { joinProject } from "@/service/project/ProjectService";
import { UserService } from "rd-component";
import React from "react";
import { useLocation, useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import queryString from 'query-string';
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { AppState } from "@/redux/types/AppState";

const TeXShareRecieved: React.FC = () => {

    const navigate = useNavigate();
    const location = useLocation();
    const search = location.search;
    const params = queryString.parse(search);
    const pid = params.projectId!;
    const { joinResult } = useSelector((state: AppState) => state.proj);

    React.useEffect(() => {
        debugger
        if (!UserService.isLoggedIn()) {
            navigate("/user/login");
        }
        handleJoin();
    }, []);

    React.useEffect(() => {
        if (joinResult && Object.keys(joinResult).length > 0) {
            navigate("/editor?pid=" + pid)
        }
    }, [joinResult]);

    const handleJoin = () => {
        if (pid) {
            let joinReq = {
                project_id: pid as String
            };
            joinProject(joinReq);

        }
    }

    return (
        <div>Share</div>
    );
}

export default TeXShareRecieved;
```

this component was loaded when user open a share link created by my app, the share link may look like this: http://dev-tex.example.top/proj/share?projectId=2f5c4956efcd45c0a7a385cac7ea0bc1, in this component I pick the parameter `projectId` and do some logic. But now I found the useLocation returns undefined. Am I missing something? the parameter only access when using navigate? what should I do to fixed this issue or get the parameter from url? This is my index.ts defined like:

```
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Provider store={store}>
      <RouterProvider router={routes} />
    </Provider>
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

Comment: Why don't you use `useSearchParams` hook?

Comment: I will try what you said, I use this way to get the parameters in my whole project.

Comment: Are you sure that this component is within router context?

Comment: yes, I am sure it under the router component context. @Konrad I have pasted the index.ts defined like code.

Comment: This can be due to a conflict between re-renders, have you tried using `useMemo` to save the value of the `location.search` everytime `location` constant changes his value? Something like this `const search = useMemo(() => location.search, [location]);` `location` or `location?.search` as depedency you can use here.

Comment: useSearchParams works for me. @Konrad